# Phone Number Regular Expression (Regex) in Python

Tags: python, regex, phone-number

Dive into python gives an amazing little tutorial on creating a regular expression for phone numbers: http://diveintopython3.ep.io/regular-expressions.html#phonenumbers

The final version comes out to look like:

```
phone_re = re.compile(r'(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})\D*(\d*)$', re.VERBOSE)
```

This works fine for almost all examples I can come up with, however I found a pretty big failure that I can't seem to fix.

If a group of 3 digits comes before the phone number it works fine. IE: 
"500 dollars off, call 123-456-7891"

If a group of 3 digits comes after the phone number it fails.  IE:
"Call 123-456-7891 for a discount of up to 500"

Any ideas on a fix that would work for both examples?

Comment: I'm always amazed how respected people in the web community wholeheartedly give flawed (i.e. US-centric) advice. This may be a good academic example to give regex a practical feel for beginners, but you should not use it in an actual application. Phone numbers do not work the same everywhere in the world.

Comment: More specifically, you should only use it in an application if you're never planning to use your application anywhere except the US.

Comment: And not even there, since not everyone might format a phone number like they should.

Comment: @Amber: "never planning to use your application anywhere except the US." is the reason why so many applications still can't cope with characters outside the US-ASCII range. It's a last-century mind-set we should finally get over with.

Comment: In defense of Dive into Python, the author states explicitly that he's parsing American phone numbers, and lists the formats in which the phone number can occur.

Comment: @Tomalak: You still have to draw the boundaries somewhere, though - especially if you're doing things like trying to parse phone numbers out of larger text, as opposed to just asking the user to "enter a phone number".

Comment: This phenomenon is also why short-sighted programmers *insist* that there won't be punctuation characters in people's names, even though apostrophe, period, hyphen, and space are all common enough. (I won't even get started on names that don't fit in ASCII.)

Comment: I don't think his intention was to parse every phone number.  Mostly likely it was to show how to use regex in Python.

Answer (score 2):

The `(\d*)$` requires that the string you're matching against end with digit characters (the `$` signifies "end of line"). Try removing the `$` if you're matching against a larger string where the phone number may not be at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your original, with some spaces (use `re.VERBOSE`, or remove the spaces):

```
(\d{3}) \D* (\d{3}) \D* (\d{4}) \D* (\d*)
```

The `\D*` will match anything that's not a digit, including words.  Maybe you should try this:

```
(\d{3}) \W* (\d{3}) \W* (\d{4}) \W* (\d*)
```

The `\W*` matches anything that's not a word.  It will match `(222) - 222 - 2222`.  However, it will not match if there is a letter between the numbers, as in `(222) x 222 - 2222`.  The last part of the match `(\d*)` appears to be looking for an extension.  These can be formatted in a variety of ways—I suggest you either drop it or refine it based on how you expect your data to look.  And, like Amber says, you should probably drop the `$`.